# Неправильно выводит данные команда eval (Бот на discord.js)

Tags: javascript

Тут у меня такая проблема. Я смог реализовать команду eval без всяких посторонних пакетов. Команда работает хорошо, идеально отображает ошибки в случае если она обнаружена. Но есть одна проблема с которой я столкнулся.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот как реализована команда:

```js
const Discord = module.require("discord.js");
const fs = require("fs");
const {MessageEmbed} = require("discord.js");
module.exports.run = async (bot,message,args) => {
    message.react("");
    if (message.deletable) {
        message.delete({timeout: 10000});
    }
    let embed = new MessageEmbed();
    const owner = "ID";
    const trusted = ["ID", "ID"];
    if (owner.includes(!message.author.id) || trusted.includes(!message.author.id)) {
        embed.setDescription(`This command is only allowed for <@!ID>, <@!ID> and <@!ID>!`);
        embed.setColor(0xff0000);
        return message.channel.send(embed).then(message => message.delete({timeout: 10000}));
    } else if (!args[0]) {
        embed.setDescription("You need to evaluate **something**!");
        embed.setColor(0xff0000)
        return message.channel.send(embed).then(message => message.delete({timeout: 10000}));
    } else if (owner.includes(message.author.id)) {
        try {
            var code = args.join(" ");
            var evaled = eval(code);
            embed.setColor(0x131359);
            embed.setTimestamp();
            embed.setFooter(bot.user.username, bot.user.displayAvatarURL);
            embed.setTitle("[Owner] Eval results");
            embed.addField("Input:", `\`\`\`js\n${code}\n\`\`\``, true);
            embed.addField("Output:", `\`\`\`js\n${evaled}\`\`\``, true);
            message.channel.send(embed).then(message => message.delete({timeout: 10000}));
        } catch (error) {
            embed.setColor(0x131359);
            embed.setTitle("\:x: Error!");
            embed.setDescription(error);
            embed.setFooter(bot.user.username, bot.user.displayAvatarURL);
            message.channel.send(embed).then(message => message.delete({timeout: 10000}));
        }
        return;
    } else if (trusted.includes(message.author.id)) {
        try {
            var code = args.join(" ");
            var evaled = eval(code);
            embed.setColor(0x131359);
            embed.setTimestamp();
            embed.setFooter(bot.user.username, bot.user.displayAvatarURL);
            embed.setTitle("[Trusted] Eval results");
            embed.addField("Input:", `\`\`\`js\n${code}\n\`\`\``, true);
            embed.addField("Output:", `\`\`\`js\n${evaled}\`\`\``, true);
            message.channel.send(embed).then(message => message.delete({timeout: 10000}));
        } catch (error) {
            embed.setColor(0x131359);
            embed.setTitle("\:x: Error!");
            embed.setDescription(error);
            embed.setFooter(bot.user.username, bot.user.displayAvatarURL);
            message.channel.send(embed).then(message => message.delete({timeout: 10000}));
        }
        return;
    } else {
        return;
    }
};
module.exports.help = {
    name: "eval",
    aliases: []
};
```

Можете подсказать из-за чего это может быть и можно ли это как-то исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Контекста маловато...
Судя по-всему, Вас не устраивает, что отображается в Output?
Если так - то это всего лишь отображение Promis`а.
Т.е. у Вас есть какая-то асинхронная функция. Пускай test

```
const test = new Promise(.....
```

Так вы пытаетесь с помощью output вывести test();
Когда необходимо

```
test().then(function(_результат_выполнения_промиса_) { _обработка результата_выполнения_ })
```

Или объявить функцию, в которой вызывается этот промис асинхронный с помощью ключевого слова async
А после, с помощью ключевого слова await дождаться результата выполнения промиса

```
const result = await test();
```